# If a friend comments on my Facebook post, will their friends see the comment if blocked?

Tags: facebook

If I post a post on my Facebook page, and my friend comments on it, will their friend see it? What if I had their friend blocked?

I don't get along with said person and blocked them a while ago, but I'm wondering since our mutual friend is interacting with my post, will the blocked person see the post even though I blocked them?

Answer (score 1):

If you are posting on your timeline they will not be able to see it. They can't see any of your activity since you have blocked them.

If you are posting on your page as you (your name), they can't see it, but if you are posting on the page as page (page name), they will be able to see it if you have not blocked them through the page, because a page's posts are public and anyone can see them since that page was not blocked to the person.

[See this to know how blocking works](https://www.facebook.com/help/131930530214371).

Answer (score 0):

No, they will not see it. According to [this Facebook help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/131930530214371), blocked users will not be able to see things that you post on your profile.